# TCL Regex Skipping Over a Set of Characters and Matching to a New line

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I'm working with expect scripting in order to ssh into a device and pull information off of it. However, I'm facing issues parsing the expect_out(buffer) for the data from the commands I send.

This is the contents of my expect_out(buffer):

```
"mca-cli-op info\r\n\r\nModel:       UAP-AC-Lite\r\nVersion:     6.0.21.13673\r\nMAC Address: 10:9f:5r:20:c5:7e\r\nIP Address:  123.123.1.123\r\nHostname:    UAP-AC-Lite\r\nUptime:      152662 seconds\r\n\r\nStatus:      Connected (http://base_controller<url;>/inform)\r\nUAP-AC-Lite-BZ.6.0.21# "
```

Right now I'm trying to get the Model (UAP-AC-LITE) without the Model tag.

So the regex expression I'm using is,

```
expect -re {(?=(Model: ))+[.*\$]}
set model "$expect_out(0,string)"
puts $model
```

The command doesn't work, but my thought process was that I would perform a look ahead for the Model tag, then match only the subsequent characters after it to the new line. I've tried replacing the "$" with \r\n but that doesn't work either. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Note: If possible, I wouldn't want to include the newline either, as it might mess up commands that I run which use these variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but the regex is incorrect. Try

```
expect -re {Model:\s+([^\r]+)}
set model $expect_out(1,string)
```

The `1` in `$expect_out(1,string)` means the first set of capturing parentheses.

Regexes are documented at http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm